# Getting wrong value when reading an xlsx file using openpyxl

Tags: python, openpyxl, xlsx

I'm trying to read values from an xlsx file containing formulas using openpyxl; however, I noticed that for some cells, I'm getting a wrong value.

#### Here's the XLSX example:

[image: the XLSX exemple.]

#### Here's the result I get:

[image: result i get.]

#### The code:

```
 wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(excel_file, data_only=True)

    # getting all sheets
    sheets = wb.sheetnames
    print(sheets)

    # getting a particular sheet
    worksheet = wb["Feuil1"]
    print(worksheet)

    # getting active sheet
    active_sheet = wb.active
    print(active_sheet)

    # reading a cell
    print(worksheet["A1"].value)

    excel_data = list()
    # iterating over the rows and
    # getting value from each cell in row
    for row in worksheet.iter_rows():
        row_data = list()
        for cell in row:
            #cell.number_format='0.0########'
            print(cell.number_format)
            row_data.append(str(cell.value))
            print(cell.value)
        excel_data.append(row_data)

    return render(request, 'myapp/index.html', {"excel_data":excel_data})
```

Comment: What's the problem? The value is a float but you can round it to the precision required.

Comment: @CharlieClark well 53*1,2 is supposed to equal exactly 63,6, so i'm wondering why the result i get is 63,59999, especially since i need the values to be accurate to the highest degree.

Answer (score -1):

Hey What you want from an open excel file means which type of format do you gate
data,
This My answer for get data from excel file with xlrd.

```
 import xlrd
 from xlrd import open_workbook
    
    fp = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete= False, suffix=filetype)
    fp.write(binascii.a2b_base64(selected file))
    workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(file name)
    sheet = workbook.sheet_by_name(sheet name)
    row = [c or '' for c in sheet.row_values(header_row)]
    first_row = [] 
     for col in range(sheet.ncols):
        first_row.append(sheet.cell_value(0,col) )
    archive_lines = []
       for row in range(1, sheet.nrows):
          elm = {}
          for col in range(sheet.ncols):
             elm[first_row[col]]=sheet.cell_value(row,col)
          archive_lines.append(elm)
```

Comment: what i don't get is why the value is calculated correctly in excel (53*1,2=63,6) but when i retrieve the data using openpyxl i get the wrong value (63.599999999999994).

Comment: but you can use openpyxl why not use xlrd

Comment: my understading is that xlrd only supports xls format and not xlsx.  .

Comment: no bro i can use xlrd for .xlsx or .xls both format you can try it out

Comment: well i tried using xlrd and i'm getting an exception "Excel xlsx file; not supported".

Comment: Support for XLSX was removed from recent versions of xlrd.